# Python: Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Question: Given a list of unordered timestamps, find the largest span of time that overlaps
For example:  [1,3],[10,15],[2,7],[11,13],[12,16],[5,8]  => [1,8] and [10,16]

I was asked to solve the above question.

My initial approach was the following:

```
times = [[1,3],[10,15],[2,7],[11,13],[12,16],[5,8]]
import itertools
def flatten(listOfLists):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
start = [i[0] for i in times]
end = [i[1] for i in times]
times = sorted(list(flatten(times)))
# 1=s, 2=s, 3=e, 5=s, 7=e, 8=e, 10=s, 11=s, 12=s, 13=e, 15=e, 16=e
num_of_e = 0
num_of_s = 0
first_s = 0
for time in times:
    if first_s == 0:
        first_s = time
    if time not in end:
        num_of_s += 1
    if time in end:
        num_of_e += 1
        if num_of_e == num_of_s:
            num_of_e = 0
            num_of_s = 0
            print [first_s, time]
            first_s = 0
```

Then, the questioner insisted that I should solve it by ordering the times first because "it's better" so I did the following

```
times = [[1,3],[10,15],[2,7],[11,13],[12,16],[5,8]]
def merge(a,b):
    return[min(a[0],b[0]), max(a[1],b[1])]
times.sort()
# [1,3] [2,7] [5,8] [10,15] [11,13] [12,16]
cur = []
for time in times:
    if not cur:
        cur = time
        continue
    if time[0] > cur[0] and time[0] < cur[1]:
        cur = merge(time,cur)
    else:
        print cur
        cur = time
print cur
```

Is there such thing as a "better" approach (or maybe another approach that could be better)? I know I could time it and see which one is faster or just evaluate based on big O notation (both O(N) for the actual work part).

Just wanted to see if you guys have any opinions on this?
Which one would you prefer and why?
Or maybe other ways to do it?

Comment: (8 - 1 = 7) **!=** (16 - 10 = 6), Am I missing something?

Comment: your first approach is `O(n*log(n))` because of the initial sort. The loop on times is `O(n)`, so the overall is `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: the OP's method prints all spans, finding the largest is then trivial

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan no. its not supposed to be same. it's to have the largest overlapping timestamp. [1,3] [2,7] [5,8] becomes [1,8]

Comment: @njzk2 what about the second sort?

Comment: @ealeon : `time[0] > cur[0]` can be `time[0] >= cur[0]` and is therefore implied by `times.sort()`

Comment: @ealeon: the second approach is `O(n*log(n))` for the same reason, the initial sort.

Comment: ok I misunderstood first..

Comment: erratum: the first approach is actually more complex than that, because of the `time in end`, which is `O(n)`, making the whole process `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @njzk2 okay so if they both have the same big o notation. which one should you go with?

Comment: however, you can reduce that by using a `set` for storing `start` and `end` values, as then the complexity of `time in end` would be `O(1)`, and therefore the overall complexity would be back to being the complexity of the initial sort.

Comment: final note: your first approach is flawed: consider `[[1,2], [2,3]]`. Sorted, this gives `[1,2,2,3]`, and `end = [2,3]` `2 not in end` returns false, it should be `2 in start` instead, which would be true.

Comment: @njzk2 that would be a special case, yes. but easily fixable in the preprocessing step to make sure start and end are unique else merge into 1-3

Comment: no need to consider a special case. just start by testing `time in start` instead of `time not in end`, as if `time` is in start, it will increment `num_of_s`, and then increment `num_of_e`, which works.

Comment: @njzk2 oh yeah you are right. and... i timed them and the second one is always faster for some reason.

Comment: there is also the issue of `[1,1]` span, which creates 2 entries both being start and end

Comment: are you using `set` for `start` and `end`?

Comment: @njzk2 using set made it slower for second one. it must be python-related stuff

Comment: that would make it faster, but for much larger data sets.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah and so you are saying you would go with second one over the first?

Comment: I find the second one easier because it is a process that seems more intuitive and natural. I prefer the second approach because shuffling together starts and ends looks like magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for eluding the risks related to `time in end` time computation and specific cases issues:

```
times = [[1,3],[10,15],[2,7],[11,13],[12,16],[5,8]]
start = [(i[0], 0) for i in times]
end = [(i[1], 1) for i in times]
# Using 0 for start and 1 for end ensures that starts are resolved before ends
times = sorted(start + end)
span_count = 0
first_s = 0
for time, is_start in times:
    if first_s == 0:
        first_s = time
    if is_start == 0:
        span_count += 1
    else:
        span_count -= 1
        if span_count == 0:
            print [first_s, time]
            first_s = 0
```

Also, it has an easily computable complexity of `O(n) (actual work) + O(n*log(n)) (sort) = O(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 1):

Speed is often the most important consideration when evaluating an algorithm, but it may not be the only one. But let's look at speed first.

It this case, there are two kinds of speed to consider: asymptotic (which is what big Ω-Θ-O notation characterizes), and non-asymptotic. Even if two algorithms have the same asymptotic behavior, one may still perform considerably better than the other because of other costs in the algorithm that will be significant at smaller data sizes.

In your first algorithm you iterate through the list two times before sorting it, and then iterate through the list a third time after sorting it. In the second answer you only iterate through the list once. I would expect the second to be faster, but in Python, performance can sometimes be surprising, so it's good to measure if you need the speed.

You may also evaluate an algorithm's use of memory. Your first algorithm creates two temporary lists of start and end times, and a third temporary list holding the sorted time spans. Those could be expensive if the data set is large! The second algorithm avoids much of this, but creates a new list of length 2 each time `merge` is called. That could still be a significant amount of memory being allocated, and might be something to look at optimizing further. There may also be some memory use hidden behind the scenes: your use of `sort`, for example, may not in fact use much less memory than `sorted` does when you look at how it's implemented.

A final consideration when evaluating an algorithm is your audience. If you are in an interview, for example, speed and memory may not be as critical for your first attempt at implementing an algorithm as clarity and style.